# if $ϵ>0$ and $f(z) = z + \frac{d_1}{z} + \frac{d_2}{z^2} + \cdots$ for $|z| > 1$ univalent, there is $C$ with $d_n \leq C(1 + ϵ)^n$ for all $n$

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series, rate-of-convergence

Let $f : \{ |z| > 1\} \rightarrow \mathbb C$ be a univalent function with a Laurent series expansion
$$f(z) = z + \frac{d_1}{z} + \frac{d_2}{z^2} + \frac{d_3}{z^3} + \cdots.$$
Prove that, or all $\epsilon > 0$, there is $C > 0$ depending on $\epsilon$ such that $|d_n| \leq C(1 + \epsilon)^n$ for all $n$.

I am not sure how we can find such a $C > 0$. We know that the expression of $f$ above is equivalent to $f(\frac{1}{z}) = \frac{1}{z} + d_1z + d_2z^2 + d_3z^3 + \cdots$ for all $\frac{1}{|z|} < 1$; how would this help us?

Comment: since the series converges for $|z|>1$ we need $|d_k|/r^k \to 0, k \to \infty$ for every $r >1$; in particular, for $r=1+\epsilon$ you get $|d_k| < (1+\epsilon)^k, k>k(\epsilon)$ and as usually bounding the $|d_k|, k=1,..k_\epsilon$ by some $c_\epsilon$ finishes the job